# How to launch VBS script file after download

Tags: vbscript, autorun

I am trying to auto launch a vbs script after it is downloaded from the website. What I am working on is a script to will auto launch applications on the local machine. The file is created and updated on the server side using php. The user is able to add and remove the applications they need to start and php will create a .vbs file with the information. The problem is my company is not willing to give me access to write to the local machine from the server because of security risks so I am trying to create a work around. So my big question is

is there a script I could add in the vbs file to auto run after it has been downloaded.

Thank you

Comment: None that I know of. Huge security risk indeed. Besides, this will only work if autorun is enabled on the target machines. And that's not so likely as the vbs autorun worm thrives on this, so you're looking only at a minute number of machines with autorun enabled.

Comment: Well I didn't think that was possible, just thought I would give it a try. Thanks. Do you know of any other way I could get it to start at all? I am new to this area so not sure it is even possible but can I use some kind of exe file that would be downloaded with it containing some sort of auto start script? Thanks again

Comment: Ignore this comment in the event that I misunderstood your post: You can take a look at [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/) and get an idea from there. They have one universal app which acts like the Windows 'Start' menu which makes all other applications accessible. As for making it run automatically after download, I don't think that's possible to enforce on current machines; the user will have to manually execute the app..

Comment: I cant really use the portable apps in this case but I really appreciate your help. darn security restrictions are making my life very difficult. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

No. This would be a huge security risk.